# Using Apache Tika Without Maven

Tags: java, apache-tika

I just want to use the Apache Tika library to extract text from Word documents and PDFs for a project I'm working on. However, every tutorial I've seen insists on using Maven (Or Ant), which I would really rather avoid.

Is there any good way to go about implementing Tika without Maven? (I apologize in advance for how little I know about packages and Maven)

Comment: I’m not familiar with Tika, but just generally you would probably just need to download the jars, perhaps from their github or from maven central. Then you would just need to include the jars on your classpath. Maven/gradle just does that for you, in addition to doing a lot more. Is there a specific reason you don’t want to use maven?

Comment: Mostly because I don't have any experience with Maven (and don't really understand it). Also, (without getting too much into details)  I want this project to be something I can just package up and export to another machine so someone else can just execute it as needed.

Comment: Do you use OSGi? Apache Tika provides an OSGi bundle that you can use